# How do I order a data frame by ID, date, then time?

Tags: r, date, time

I have this in R, and I want to put each ID number next to each other and then sort by Date, finally by Time... Is this possible?

```
   ID Val      Date  Time
1   1 0.7 1/13/2013 12:00
2   2 1.6 1/13/2013 12:00
3   3 0.5 1/13/2013 12:00
4   4 2.1 1/13/2013 12:00
5   5 1.2 1/13/2013 12:00
6   1 1.0 1/13/2013 13:00
7   2 1.1 1/13/2013 13:00
8   3 0.9 1/13/2013 13:00
9   4 2.4 1/13/2013 13:00
10  5 0.8 1/13/2013 13:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`order` can take multiple arguments to do just this:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID Val      Date  Time
1   1 0.7 1/13/2013 12:00
2   2 1.6 1/13/2013 12:00
3   3 0.5 1/13/2013 12:00
4   4 2.1 1/13/2013 12:00
5   5 1.2 1/13/2013 12:00
6   1 1.0 1/13/2013 13:00
7   2 1.1 1/13/2013 13:00
8   3 0.9 1/13/2013 13:00
9   4 2.4 1/13/2013 13:00
10  5 0.8 1/13/2013 13:00",header=TRUE)


df[with(df,order(ID,Date,Time)),]
```

Note that I didn't yet convert `Date` and `Time` to appropriate time classes yet here, which wil give better results.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

`orderBy` from doBy package is another alternative:

```
> library(doBy)
> orderBy(~ID+Date+Time, data=DF)
```

Comment: Glad to be useful. @shirleywu consider accepting one of the answer as the correct one by doing clic in the the green tickmark right below the score button